# Why my codelite execute 'make -j 0'

Tags: codelite, cmake-gui

I'm using cmake-GUI on windows, generating for codelite, to build a simple "hello world" project (https://github.com/jameskbride/cmake-hello-world). I'm trying to use cygwin compilers but when I run the build command, I got the following error:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /C C:/cygwin64/bin/make.exe -j 0
----------Building project:[ Debugging - Debug ]----------
make: the '-j' option requires a positive integer argument
Usage: make [options] [target] ...
```

Why it is happening?!?

My cygwin folder is in PATH. In cygwin terminal the project works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project was generated by `CMake` - this means that the project is set to `custom` project so the command to execute (in your case `make -j0`) is set in the `Project Settings->Customize->Custom build` page.

On that page you have several entries with different titles (`Build`, `Clean` etc)
Double click each entry so it will open in Edit mode and remove the `-j0` option

This looks like a bug in `CodeLite - CMake` generator